# Latest Flash Player release (12) breaks mediaelement.js support for IE8 and below

Tags: mediaelement.js

since Adobe released Flash player 12 2 days ago, the mediaelement.js Flash video player is not working properly anymore.

The video plays nicely but no video controls appear. Looking at the DOM, I can't see any of the nodes that mediaelement.js is supposed to create.

Any advice?

Thanks
Fabio

Comment: https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/1078

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, Mediaelement.js version 2.13.2 fixes this issue. See https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement#version-history and https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/1078.